# jQuery $.ajax POST function into WPSC

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am using Wordpress Shopping cart. I want to append or modify the product name based on 3 variations the same thing goes for the price to. 
I have tried to implement a simple Jquery on click event to an image using the AJAX $.post method within the single product page. It's not sending the data value even if I encode it with JSON. I must say that I'm new with JSON and PHP. Thanks in advance !

In the single product page

```
$(function() {
$('#div_img_link').click(function() { 
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: "test value",
 // dataType : "json",
    url: '../wpsc-cart_widget.php',
    cache:false
    });
  });
 });
```

In wpsc-cart_widget.php

```
 $name=wpsc_cart_item_name();

if (isset($_POST['data'])){
$value1 = $_POST['data'];  
  }else{
  $value1 = "";
}

 echo "$name $value1";
```

I know that are some similar posts out there I've read them all can't figure it out. I want to know if the WPSC can perform the jQuery POST function without refreshing the page. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

[schematics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLTIO.jpg)

### **EDIT**

SCHEMATICS 2 - to be more concise !

[What I'm trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYoS4.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SEA, you're missing a function to handle the response that comes back from the server.

I would expect to see something like this :

```
$(function() {
    $('#div_img_link').click(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            url: '../wpsc-cart_widget.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: "test value",
            dataType : "JSON",
            cache:false,
            success: function(data) {
                //do something here with the data.
                //eg.
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                //do something here if an error occurs.
                //eg.
                alert("an error occurred");
            },
        });
    });
});
```

The best place to learn more about ajax is [the ajax() page in the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

You also need to ensure that the server response and the client expectation are compatible. With a client expectation of `dataType: "JSON"`, you must ensure that the server returns a [json-encoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) response. Json-encoding is only necessary for multiple data in a single response. A single data item can be sent unencoded.

### EDIT:

After seeing your Schematic 2, I think your ajax request data should look something like this :

```
data: {
    'pid': '12345678',
    'quantity': '1'
),
```

where `pid` is the "product id" and `quantity` is how many of the product the user wants to add to his/her basket.

But surely the WPSC documentation includes examples of this stuff? You shouldn't have to work it out for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Indeed I wasn't making any verification, although the message is displayed within the alert box, my interest is to change the `value1` form the php file so it can be posted in the sopping cart form. I don't understand what should be put inside the `success` `function` for this change to occur. My logic is stuck, clearly I can't figure out the syntax. An simple example or explication how to display `value1` it's all I need.

Comment: What I understand so far is: `onclick` event `$.ajax` function sends trough `POST` the `data` -> `test value` into the php file where there is verified if it is `posted` and if so changes the content of `value1` with `test value` then it must be displayed in the `sopping cart` widget (if the click was mad if not display blank). The `JSON encoded` it is commented I have been following some tutorials and examples and tried even with the encoding method, and yes I was decrypting it inside the php file with `json_decode($_POST[...]`

Comment: Hey thanks again for the response, yes wp does that for me the product id is shown the quantity as well my problem is that I have some variations to the initial product (options) that the user may or may not select. When that happens I want that particular option to be displayed in the product name along whit the initial PID eg: product + option(test). Can you see now what I'm describing ? As well for the price. Initial price is showing after selecting option 1,2,3 add another value to the price. In fact all I need is in the schematics ONCLICK add/dispay VALUE to the product/price. Thank you!

Comment: It all resumes at how can I echo another variable to the initial `$name=wpsc_cart_item_name();` base upon click function `$('#div_img_link').click(function()`

Comment: Wp it really helps because the submit button `add to cart` it's refreshing the product listing. So based on my logic it must index the new value that has been send via `POST` function.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Just changing the text client-side (a) doesn't require a server-side call, and (b) will still show exactly the same product, same PID, same image, but with a different name. Any good shopping cart plugin should already cater for product variants (different colors or different sizes or both). It may or may not cater for different prices per variant.